# Get PropertyInfo from multiple property objects found in an Expression object

Tags: linq, linq-expressions

I need to change a function that accepts one Expression with one property inside and give it the ability to work with 2 properties at least.

I have the following base class that contains nested ElementHelper class

```
public class DomainObjectViewModel<TModel> where TModel : DomainObject
{

    public class ElementHelper
    {
        public static void Create<T1>(TModel model, Expression<Func<TModel, T1>> expression)
        {
            var getPropertyInfo = GetPropertyInfo(expression);
            //Do cool stuff
        }
        private static PropertyInfo GetPropertyInfo<T1>(Expression<Func<TModel, T1>> propertyExpression)
        {
            return (PropertyInfo)((MemberExpression)propertyExpression.Body).Member;
        }
    }
}
```

-ElementHelper class contains a Create function that gets the propertyInfo of the expression and only works if you pass one property in the expression.

Then I have the following inherited class that uses the helper function in the constructor.

```
public class ProductViewModel : DomainObjectViewModel<ProductEditViewModel>
{
    public ProductViewModel(ProductEditViewModel model)
    {
        //It works for one property in the Expression
        ElementHelper.Create(model, x => x.LaunchDate);
        //Give the ability to pass multiple paramenters in the expression  
        ElementHelper.Create(model, x => new { x.LaunchDate, x.ApplyLaunchDateChanges });
    }
}
```

I think I can use NewExpression (**new { x.LaunchDate, x.ApplyLaunchDateChanges }**) in order to pass it a collection of properties, but I cannot make it work.

- Would you use same approach?
- How you can split the passed Expression so you can get the propertyinfo of each properties found in the NewExpression object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, since `ElementHelper.GetPropertyInfo` is your own method, you can decide what is allowed to pass, and then handle it appropriately inside that method.

Currently you handle only `MemberExpression`, so that's why it works only with single property accessor. If you want to be able to pass `new { ... }`, you need to add support for `NewExpression` like this:

```
private static IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> GetPropertyInfo<T1>(Expression<Func<TModel, T1>> propertyExpression)
{
    var memberExpression = propertyExpression.Body as MemberExpression;
    if (memberExpression != null)
        return Enumerable.Repeat((PropertyInfo)memberExpression.Member, 1);
    var newExpression = propertyExpression.Body as NewExpression;
    if (newExpression != null)
        return newExpression.Arguments.Select(item => (PropertyInfo)((MemberExpression)item).Member);
    return Enumerable.Empty<PropertyInfo>(); // or throw exception
}
```